# How to limit each `do` loop by a different variable

Tags: ruby, loops, each, limit

I'm working on a bot. I have ships, each put in an array `my_ships`. Each ship is given an `id` when it is created independent of who created it, and each ship can be destroyed. This is the first array:

```
ship = Ship.new(
  player_id, id,
  Float(x),
  Float(y),
  Integer(hp),
  Integer(status), 
  Integer(progress),
  Integer(planet)
)
```

Each iteration sends commands. I run into timeout issues. I only have enough time to run ~100.

How do I limit my `each` loop to run only 100 times?

```
my_ships(0, 100).each do |ship|
```

gets me less ships to use as some are destroyed, and they are ordered by their id.

Comment: Are you looking for `next` keyword?

Comment: May be you should remove the destroyed ships before running the loop: `my_ships.reject(&:destroyed?)(0, 100).each ...` Replace `destroyed?` with the method you use for checking if a ship is destroyed.

Comment: Why are you doing my_ships(0, 100)? This is not valid syntax for array. You should do my_ships(0...100) or my_ships.first(100).

Comment: Sorry, I left out important details unintentionally, the bot does not create anything, it only gives commands and reads information given to it, and I cannot change that information. The bot plays a game, the game engine creates and destroys. The bot can only access the information given each turn. But I believe .first() is the answer I needed to the question.

Comment: @ZachVondrasek If the question is answered, please accept the answer that you are satisfied with, and the question will be automatically marked as such. Please do not add such messages to your question. That is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this isn't in some sort of database, where you should use a database query to select and limit (since nothing db-related is tagged), you can make use of [`Enumerable#lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) (this is a method on array's as well, since array's are Enumerable). You'll first want to select only the ships that are not destroyed and then take only the [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-first) 100 of those:

```
my_ships.lazy.select do |ship|
  # Some logic to see if a ship is allowed to be iterated
end.first(100).each do |ship|
  # your loop that runs commands
end
```

if it makes more sense, you can use [`reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) instead of [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

```
my_ships.lazy.reject do |ship|
  # Some logic to see if a ship should not be iterated
end.first(100).each do |ship|
  # your loop that runs commands
end
```

to see a little clearer what this will do for you, consider the following example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
numbers.lazy.select do |number|
  puts "running check for #{number}"
  number.even?
end.first(2).each do |number|
  puts "doing something with #{number}"
end
# running check for 1
# running check for 2
# running check for 3
# running check for 4
# doing something with 2
# doing something with 4
```

So in this example, I want to run a loop for the first 2 even numbers...if I just take the first 2 numbers, I get 1 even and 1 odd; I also don't want to loop through the entire list, because the check for *is this even?* might be expensive (it's not, but your check could be), or your list could be large and you only need a few items. This loops through just enough to get me the first 2 numbers that match my criteria and then let's me run my loop on them.

Comment: Thank you for the help, me being at basics level in ruby being edited out of the original post made it seem like I was asking for more, I didn't know about .first()

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088611/how-to-limit-each-do-loop-by-a-different-variable#comment83151976_48088611) by @user3309314 you may wish to use `next`.

```
arr = (1..100).to_a
enum = arr.to_enum

hun = loop.with_object [] do |_,o|
  if o.size == 10
    break o
  elsif enum.peek.even?
    o << enum.next
  else
    enum.next
  end
end

hun #=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

This `loop` goes through each element of `arr` via enumeration and adds it to another array `o` if it satisfies the condition `even?`. The loop `break`s when `o.size == 10`.

Might be easier to create a more explicit enumerator then take from that. That way you can vary how many elements you need `enum.take(8)` gets you the first 8 elements etc.

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  arr = (1..100).to_a
  enum = arr.to_enum
  loop { enum.peek.even? ? y << enum.next : enum.next }
end

enum.take 10 #=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, me being at basics level in ruby being edited out of the original post made it seem like I was asking for more, I didn't know about .first()